# is unescaping a javascript pre-escaped function a bad idea for performance?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, javascript-framework

I want to pre-escape part of my javascript code and then include it in my page in the form of  eval(unescape([code])). would I be sacrificing performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about hiding your JavaScript code from spiders. It should be the least of your concerns, especially since they don't bother to look at it (except looking for more links to crawl).

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2007/11/spiders-view-of-web-20.html

Comment: but I'm sure they do to prevent black hat SEO.

Comment: @Neo: maybe you could explain _why_ you want to hide your JS from spiders.

Comment: I want to know about the performance of eval(usescape([code]))?

Comment: @Neo: `eval` is slow, and generally regarded as evil (take that with a grain of salt). [Don't `eval` what you don't need to.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

Comment: you are wrong, google will parse pages every once in a while with attention to javascript, I even think it might be a spider that crawls using the gui, like opperating a browser but that I don't know about.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide something from spiders, use an external script and setup your robots.txt .

"good" spiders will accept that, "bad" spiders will take a look anyway if they want to.

Answer (score 1):

### Unicode character escape sequences

example

```
var \u0062\u0061\u006E\u0061\u006E\u0061 = "\u0062\u0061\u006E\u0061\u006E\u0061";
```

is parsed as

```
var banana = "banana";
```

---

### Base-36 decoding

(only for case-insensitive alphanumeric data)

```
parseInt("banana", 36);
> 683010982

683010982 .toString(36);
> "banana"
```

This could work for certain types of data if you split it up and delimit the numbers.

---

### Base-64 encoding

You can find an implementation [here](http://phpjs.org/functions/base64_encode:358)...

```
base64_encode("banana banana banana!")
> "YmFuYW5hIGJhbmFuYSBiYW5hbmEh"

base64_decode("YmFuYW5hIGJhbmFuYSBiYW5hbmEh")
> "banana banana banana!"
```

---

### Base-85 encoding

Packs things a bit smaller than base-64. Less popular format, might have to dig for an implementation or make your own.